# Cant select a array value using the key which has *_ on its key name

Tags: php, arrays, casting

Im using a API which returns a object which I then turn into an array to using in my API. But I cant seem to select the values using the keys which have *_ on their name. Im not sure why. Here is a how the array looks:

```
Array
(
    [*_apiKey] => XXXXXXXXXXXXX
    [*_values] => Array
        (
            [carrier] => XXXXXXXXXXXXX
            [tracking_number] => XXXXXXXXXXXXX
            [address_from] => Shippo_Object Object
                (
                    [_apiKey:protected] => XXXXXXXXXXXXX
                    [_values:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [city] => XXXXXXXXXXXXX
                            [state] => 
                            [zip] => XXXXXXXXXXXXX
                            [country] => XXXXXXXXXXXXX
                        )

                    [_unsavedValues:protected] => Shippo_Util_Set Object
                        (
                            [_elts:Shippo_Util_Set:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [_transientValues:protected] => Shippo_Util_Set Object
                        (
                            [_elts:Shippo_Util_Set:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [address_to] => Shippo_Object Object
                (
                    [_apiKey:protected] => XXXXXXXXXXXXX
                    [_values:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [city] => XXXXXXXXXXXXX
                            [state] => 
                            [zip] => XXXXXXXXXXXXX
                            [country] => XXXXXXXXXXXXX
                        )

                    [_unsavedValues:protected] => Shippo_Util_Set Object
                        (
                            [_elts:Shippo_Util_Set:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [_transientValues:protected] => Shippo_Util_Set Object
                        (
                            [_elts:Shippo_Util_Set:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [eta] => 
            [servicelevel] => Shippo_Object Object
                (
                    [_apiKey:protected] => XXXXXXXXXXXXX
                    [_values:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [token] => 
                            [name] => 
                        )

                    [_unsavedValues:protected] => Shippo_Util_Set Object
                        (
                            [_elts:Shippo_Util_Set:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [_transientValues:protected] => Shippo_Util_Set Object
                        (
                            [_elts:Shippo_Util_Set:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [metadata] => 
            [tracking_status] => Shippo_Object Object
                (
                    [_apiKey:protected] => XXXXXXXXXXXXX
                    [_values:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [object_created] => 2017-08-04T23:05:43.651Z
                            [object_updated] => 2017-08-04T23:05:43.651Z
                            [object_id] => XXXXXXXXXXXXX
                            [status] => UNKNOWN (¡¡¡This is what I want to select!!!!)
                            [status_details] => Shipment information received
                            [status_date] => 2017-08-04T06:40:00Z
                            [location] => 
                        )

                    [_unsavedValues:protected] => Shippo_Util_Set Object
                        (
                            [_elts:Shippo_Util_Set:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [_transientValues:protected] => Shippo_Util_Set Object
                        (
                            [_elts:Shippo_Util_Set:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [tracking_history] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Shippo_Object Object
                        (
                            [_apiKey:protected] => XXXXXXXXXXXXX
                            [_values:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [object_created] => 2017-08-04T23:05:43.651Z
                                    [object_id] => XXXXXXXXXXXXX
                                    [status] => UNKNOWN
                                    [status_details] => Shipment information received
                                    [status_date] => 2017-08-04T06:40:00Z
                                    [location] => 
                                )

                            [_unsavedValues:protected] => Shippo_Util_Set Object
                                (
                                    [_elts:Shippo_Util_Set:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [_transientValues:protected] => Shippo_Util_Set Object
                                (
                                    [_elts:Shippo_Util_Set:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [transaction] => 
            [messages] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [*_unsavedValues] => Shippo_Util_Set Object
        (
            [_elts:Shippo_Util_Set:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [*_transientValues] => Shippo_Util_Set Object
        (
            [_elts:Shippo_Util_Set:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [*_retrieveOptions] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Here is the var_dump of the same array:

```
array(5) {
  ["*_apiKey"]=>
  string(52) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  ["*_values"]=>
  array(11) {
    ["carrier"]=>
    string(11) "dhl_express"
    ["tracking_number"]=>
    string(10) "XXXXXXXXX"
    ["address_from"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["*_apiKey"]=>
      string(52) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      ["*_values"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["city"]=>
        string(9) "xxxxxxxxxxx"
        ["state"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["zip"]=>
        string(5) "xxxxx"
        ["country"]=>
        string(2) "MX"
      }
      ["*_unsavedValues"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      ["*_transientValues"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      ["*_retrieveOptions"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["address_to"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["*_apiKey"]=>
      string(52) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      ["*_values"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["city"]=>
        string(9) "xxxxxxxxx"
        ["state"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["zip"]=>
        string(5) "xxxxxxxxx"
        ["country"]=>
        string(2) "MX"
      }
      ["*_unsavedValues"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      ["*_transientValues"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      ["*_retrieveOptions"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["eta"]=>
    NULL
    ["servicelevel"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["*_apiKey"]=>
      string(52) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      ["*_values"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["token"]=>
        NULL
        ["name"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["*_unsavedValues"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      ["*_transientValues"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      ["*_retrieveOptions"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["metadata"]=>
    NULL
    ["tracking_status"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["*_apiKey"]=>
      string(52) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      ["*_values"]=>
      array(7) {
        ["object_created"]=>
        string(24) "2017-08-07T17:10:41.233Z"
        ["object_updated"]=>
        string(24) "2017-08-07T17:10:41.233Z"
        ["object_id"]=>
        string(32) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        ["status"]=>
        string(7) "TRANSIT"
        ["status_details"]=>
        string(21) "With delivery courier"
        ["status_date"]=>
        string(20) "2017-08-07T10:04:14Z"
        ["location"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["*_unsavedValues"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      ["*_transientValues"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      ["*_retrieveOptions"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["tracking_history"]=>
    array(6) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["*_apiKey"]=>
        string(52) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        ["*_values"]=>
        array(6) {
          ["object_created"]=>
          string(24) "2017-08-04T23:05:43.651Z"
          ["object_id"]=>
          string(32) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          ["status"]=>
          string(7) "UNKNOWN"
          ["status_details"]=>
          string(29) "Shipment information received"
          ["status_date"]=>
          string(20) "2017-08-04T06:40:00Z"
          ["location"]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["*_unsavedValues"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
        ["*_transientValues"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
        ["*_retrieveOptions"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(5) {
        ["*_apiKey"]=>
        string(52) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        ["*_values"]=>
        array(6) {
          ["object_created"]=>
          string(24) "2017-08-07T17:10:41.233Z"
          ["object_id"]=>
          string(32) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          ["status"]=>
          string(7) "TRANSIT"
          ["status_details"]=>
          string(18) "Shipment picked up"
          ["status_date"]=>
          string(20) "2017-08-04T20:20:56Z"
          ["location"]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["*_unsavedValues"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
        ["*_transientValues"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
        ["*_retrieveOptions"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      array(5) {
        ["*_apiKey"]=>
        string(52) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        ["*_values"]=>
        array(6) {
          ["object_created"]=>
          string(24) "2017-08-07T17:10:41.233Z"
          ["object_id"]=>
          string(32) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          ["status"]=>
          string(7) "TRANSIT"
          ["status_details"]=>
          string(31) "Processed at MONTERREY - MEXICO"
          ["status_date"]=>
          string(20) "2017-08-04T21:09:30Z"
          ["location"]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["*_unsavedValues"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
        ["*_transientValues"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
        ["*_retrieveOptions"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [3]=>
      array(5) {
        ["*_apiKey"]=>
        string(52) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        ["*_values"]=>
        array(6) {
          ["object_created"]=>
          string(24) "2017-08-07T17:10:41.233Z"
          ["object_id"]=>
          string(32) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          ["status"]=>
          string(7) "TRANSIT"
          ["status_details"]=>
          string(39) "Departed Facility in MONTERREY - MEXICO"
          ["status_date"]=>
          string(20) "2017-08-05T00:16:59Z"
          ["location"]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["*_unsavedValues"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
        ["*_transientValues"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
        ["*_retrieveOptions"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [4]=>
      array(5) {
        ["*_apiKey"]=>
        string(52) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        ["*_values"]=>
        array(6) {
          ["object_created"]=>
          string(24) "2017-08-07T17:10:41.233Z"
          ["object_id"]=>
          string(32) "710e995c15654532bb23425b4c30426e"
          ["status"]=>
          string(7) "TRANSIT"
          ["status_details"]=>
          string(74) "Arrived at Delivery Facility in
                        CHIHUAHUA - MEXICO"
          ["status_date"]=>
          string(20) "2017-08-07T08:02:41Z"
          ["location"]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["*_unsavedValues"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
        ["*_transientValues"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
        ["*_retrieveOptions"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [5]=>
      array(5) {
        ["*_apiKey"]=>
        string(52) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        ["*_values"]=>
        array(6) {
          ["object_created"]=>
          string(24) "2017-08-07T17:10:41.233Z"
          ["object_id"]=>
          string(32) "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
          ["status"]=>
          string(7) "TRANSIT"
          ["status_details"]=>
          string(21) "With delivery courier"
          ["status_date"]=>
          string(20) "2017-08-07T10:04:14Z"
          ["location"]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["*_unsavedValues"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
        ["*_transientValues"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
        ["*_retrieveOptions"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
    ["transaction"]=>
    NULL
    ["messages"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["*_unsavedValues"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["*_transientValues"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Shippo_Util_Set_elts"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["*_retrieveOptions"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

And here is how Im trying to get to it (`$tracking_dhl` is the array above):

```
$tracking_dhl_status = (array) $tracking_dhl["*_values"]["tracking_status"];

echo "Traking status: " . $tracking_dhl_status["_values:protected"]["status"] . "<br>";
```

But I always get a error that the key does not exist.

Comment: You are trying to access a protected class member, these are not arrays. The name ':protected' is just print_r trying to print a class as an array, informing you of the member's protection type. Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r` to get more information about the variable you're dumping out.

Comment: First of all these are not arrays, but objects. Thus your "API" (→ that part would be worth elaborating on) already converts the data structure to an internal object representation. Which usually means there are accessor wrappers (more or less senseful ones).

Comment: Well this object is what is returned to me in a call I make to an API. I then cast the object to array and try getting the status of the shippment. What would I have to do to be able to get that value if it has that *_?

Comment: Use `var_dump()`, not `print_r()`. var_dump()` will show you *far* more useful information about your data.

Comment: I added the var_dump to the question. I still cant select the status from the tracking_status for some reason. Any ideas how or what I would have to do to select it ?

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a workaround, as suggested in another thread, I changed the object to array using a foreach loop where I took the key and errase the *_ and presto. Here is the code:

```
public function toArray($obj) {
    if (is_object($obj)) $obj = (array)$obj;
    if (is_array($obj)) {
        $new = array();
        foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
            if (strpos(substr($key,0, 4), '_') !== false) {
                $new[substr($key, 4)] = $this->toArray($val);
            } else {
                $new[$key] = $this->toArray($val);
            }
            //$new[str_replace("_", "", $key)] = $this->toArray($val);
        }
    } else {
        $new = $obj;
    }

    return $new;
}
```

This function helped me convert the object to array and change the key name to take out the *_ which in reality uses 4 chars. I still don't understand that. Even so, with that you get rid of the pesky protected items in an object haha. I saw another one with a `ltrim()` instead of my `substr()` and if cases I made, but I don't know why the `ltrim()` didnt work for me. I Hope this helps anyone.